# xslt - match ID's across two XML files and replace all ids and names

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xsd, xslt-2.0

I have 2 XML files with data about same items, and i have to change only the IDs from the first XML.

1.xml First data looks like this (with more attributes that are irrelevant to the comparison):

```
 <channel id="Digi">
    <display-name lang="tr">Digi</display-name>
    <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
  </channel>
<channel id="Star">
    <display-name lang="tr">Star</display-name>
    <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
  </channel>
<channel id="ATV">
    <display-name lang="tr">ATV</display-name>
    <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
  </channel>
```

2.xml Second data look like this (with more attributes and possible sub-elements):

```
 <channel id="Digi.TR">
    <display-name lang="tr">Digi.TR</display-name>
    <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
  </channel>
<channel id="Star.tr">
    <display-name lang="tr">Star.tr</display-name>
    <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
  </channel>
<channel id="ATV.tr">
    <display-name lang="tr">ATV.tr</display-name>
    <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
  </channel>
```

Is it possible to run some script/code/xslt stylesheet to replace the ids in the  First 1.xml with the ids from the Second Date 2.xml?

I am not very familiar with stylesheets and not sure where to begin with coding something like that

For each item in 1.xml, read attributes "id" and "name"find them with same "id" and "name" in 2.xml replace "id" and "name" in 1.xml.

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Is the sequence of the `<channel>` elements same in both the XMLs i.e. if `channel = Digi` is first element in `1.xml`, will it also be first element in `2.xml`?

Comment: Yes its the same only the content is other

Answer (score 0):

Assume that both XMLs have a root node, e.g. called `<root>`, each wrapping the XML contents. This is necessary for the XMLs to be well-formed because both you XMLs are not.

Now the `First 1.xml` is copied by the *identity template* and while copying all relevant `id` attribute nodes are replaced with the respective `id` values from `Second Date 2.xml` by using the `document()` function to include the second XML file.

To replace the `id` attributes in the first XML with the respective ones from the second XML each pair is compared with `starts-with()` in a predicate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="channel/@id">
    <xsl:variable name="ID" select="." />    <!-- save @id from First 1.xml in variable $ID -->
    <xsl:attribute name="id">                <!-- reconstruct id attribute -->
        <!-- copy value from second XML to first XML if id attributes partially match -->
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(document('Second Date 2.xml')/root/channel[starts-with(@id,$ID)]/@id)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
    <channel id="Digi.TR">
        <display-name lang="tr">Digi</display-name>
        <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
    </channel>
    <channel id="Star.tr">
        <display-name lang="tr">Star</display-name>
        <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
    </channel>
    <channel id="ATV.tr">
        <display-name lang="tr">ATV</display-name>
        <url>http://www.digiturk.com.tr</url>
    </channel>
</root>
```